# Сохранение массива byte полученных с камеры напрямую в файл

Tags: android, android-camera

Делаю фото с камеры(не стороннее приложение). Хочу сохранить изображение на диск. 
Есть ли способ напрямую записать byte[] в файл без промежуточной конвертации в bitmap?
сейчас выглядит вот так. работает не очень быстро, как мне кажется из-за конвертации.

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(source, 0, source.size())
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream)
```

Напрямую записать byte[] в поток не получится(предвидя такие ответы), надо поддержать формат jpeg.

Comment: bitmap по сути и есть байтовый массив. Поэтому никакой промежуточной конвертации нет

Answer (score 1):

Если промежуточный `bitmap` совсем не нужен, то получайте фото с камеры напрямую в виде файла. С помощью подобного интента.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), <имя файла>));
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
```

Comment: такой вариант вообще не устраивает. я пишу свою камеру :)

Comment: тогда придется написать и свой конвертер чего-то там в виде byte[] в jpeg :-)